# What are the options to remove underlining of links in E-mail clients?

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, text-decorations

*This might seem asked a thousand times- and that is true- but somehow all of the answers I've tried have not worked.*

I simply **cannot** find a way to remove the text-underline of links in E-mail message for Apple Mail, Gmail (Web) and Outlook 2007 (sending client). No matter what I try, It simply stays underlined on either one or all of them.

It doesn't matter if I simply use a few hyperlinks of a whole formatted E-mail signature, as completely below.

**Note:** *"I've got "Reduce message size by removing format information not necessary to display the message" ticked off"*.

---

Drop down any suggestion in the comments. I will try everything and report what works so you can convert it into an answer.

---

***Please, do not mark this as duplicate***
Instead of marking this question as 'duplicate', let's create a summarized version of all possible options to remove underlining of hyperlinks

---

**My import workflow**
I simply open the HTML file, select everything and copy it in Outlook signature editor. And when sending an E-mail I make sure "aA HTML" is selected, instead of 'plain text' or RTF.

---

Tried options:

- `<a href="#">This is a link</a>`
- `<a href="#" text-decoration: none>This is a link</a>`
- `<a href="#" style="text-decoration: none">This is a link</a>`
- `<a href="#" style="text-decoration: none !important">This is a link</a>`
- `<a href="#" style="text-decoration: none !important; text-decoration: none">This is a link</a>`
- `<a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; text-decoration: none !important">This is a link</a>`
- Using `<style>a { text-decoration: none"}</style>`
- Using `a.link { text-decoration: none"}

And I'm sure I forgot a few

---

```html
<br/><br/>

<table width="600" style="line-height: 1.5; font-size: 8pt; color: #888888; font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; border-bottom: 1px solid #009984">
 <tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid #009984"> 
  <td width="150">
   <img nosend=”1″ border=”0″ alt="profile image" width="125" height="70" src="http://lorempixel.com/125/70" alt="personal-photo"/>
  </td> 
  <td width="450">
   <span style="color:#444; font-weight: bold">Kind regards, </span><br/>
   <span style="color:#009984; font-size: 20pt; font-weight: bold;">Name</span> | CEO<br/>
   <b style="color: #009984">T:</b> Extension 010&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<b style="color: #009984">E:</b> <a href="#" style="color: #888; text-decoration:none">Email</a>
  </td>
 </tr> 
 <tr>
  <td style="font-size: 4pt;">
   &nbsp;
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>

<table width="600" style="line-height: 1.5; font-size: 8pt; color: #888888; font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; border-bottom: 1px solid #009984">

 <tr>
  <td style="font-size: 4pt;">
   &nbsp;
  </td>
 </tr> 
<html>
 <tr> 
  <td width="150"> 
   <img nosend=”1″ border=”0″ alt="TTR-logo" src="http://lorempixel.com/125/70" alt="TTR-logo"/>
  </td> 

  <td width="150" valign="top"> 
   <strong><b style="color: #444">Business Name</b></strong><br/>
   Line 1<br/>
   Line 2 <br/>
   Line 3
  </td> 

  <td width="150" valign="top"> 
   <strong><b style="color: #444">Contact information</b></strong><br/>

   <table style="line-height: 1.5; font-size: 8pt; color: #888888; font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;">
    <tr>
     <td width="20">
      <b style="color: #009984">T:</b><br/>
      <b style="color: #009984">E:</b><br/>
      <b style="color: #009984">W:</b><br/>
     </td>
     <td width="125" style="text-decoration: none">
      <a href="#" style="color: #888; text-decoration:none;">Phone number</a><br/>
      <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none !important; text-decoration: none" >Email</a><br/>
      <a href="#" style="color: #888; text-decoration: none"><span style="color: #888; text-decoration: none">Site</span></a><br/>
     </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
   
    <td>

    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
  </td> 

  <td width="150" valign="top"> 
   <strong><b style="color: #444">Social Channels</b></strong><br/>
   <a href="#"><img nosend=”1″ border=”0″ src="http://www.ttr.nl/media/23442/skypeicon.jpg" alt="skype-icon"/></a> 
   <a href="#"><img nosend=”1″ border=”0″ src="http://www.ttr.nl/media/23443/youtube.jpg" alt="YouTube-icon"/></a>
  </td> 
 </tr> 

 <tr>
  <td style="font-size: 4pt;">
   &nbsp;
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>

<table width="600" style="line-height: 1.5; font-size: 8pt; color: #888888; font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; border-bottom: 1px solid #009984">
 <tr>
  <td style="font-size: 4pt;">
   &nbsp;
  </td>
 </tr>


 <tr>
  <td width="300">
   <b style="color: #444">Products: </b> <br/>
   Product line up
  </td>

  <td width="300">
   <b style="color: #444">Worldwide offices:</b> <br/>
   All our offices should be here  
  </td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
  <td style="font-size: 4pt;">
   &nbsp;
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>

<table width="600" style="line-height: 1.5; font-size: 6pt; color: #888888; font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;">
 <tr>
  <td style="font-size: 4pt;">
   &nbsp;
  </td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
  <td width="600">
   <p style="line-height:1.5">
   Copyright line
   </p>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
</html>
```

This is how it shows up:
[image]

Comment: "This might seem asked a thousand times- and that is true- but somehow all of the answers I've tried have not worked" - a jsfiddle please?

Comment: All suggestions I've tried I have pasted below. And I'm adding my HTML to the question. Have a moment. :)

Comment: Yeah, and make a jsfiddle, or a stack snippet please :)

Comment: Done ;) As you can see in a browser there is no problem. But go ahead and paste it in Outlook and sent it to either a Gmail or Apple Mail client. At least in my case underlining is still visible on a few links..